# link two xml files and access one from instance of the other

Tags: xml

Good day every one. i have two xml documents named pages.xml 
and images.xml. here are they:

```html
//pages.xml
<Pages> 
    <!--some stuff-->
    <title>-----------</title>
    <link>-------------</link>
    <description>----------</description>  
    <content>------------</content> 
    <images ID = "ANOTHER_FILE">
       <!--i want to fetched these items from images.xml-->
    </images>    
    <!--close some stuff-->  
</Pages>

//images.xml 
    <!-- some stuff--> 
 <images ID = "ANOTHER_FILE">
    <IMG1>path to this Image </IMG1>
    <IMG2>path to this Image </IMG2>
    <IMG3>path to this Image </IMG3>
    <IMG4>path to this Image </IMG4>
 </images>
    <!--close some stuff-->​
```

My question is, i want to be able to fetch items
within the images tag in images.xml.that is, is 
it possible to link both files and access one from
an instance of the other ? something like this:

//xpath select all tags under Pages/home/images
 $xml = funLoadxml("pages.xml");
 $result = $xml->xpath("Pages/images/*")

please guide me ! thanks.

Comment: No, it is not possible with just XML

Comment: @sam so, how do i go about it ? is there something similar to what i am trying to achieve ?

Comment: Depends on your environment. Needs more information to get an answer, since we only know you use XML, nothing more.

Comment: @Sami. sorry it took me long to reply your comment. i am using it on a wamp server installed on a 32 bits windows machine. thanks !